# Front Controller in MVC c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, front-controller

Could someone tell me which is the front controller in MVC 4 c# visual studio please?

I mean, i have to do a big application and i want add security to restrict the access to the controllers and actions. I used to do this in the Logistic of the Front Controller in CodeIgniter, adding a token to the session, so if someone wanted to write the route manually on the browser he couldnt access.

I've been reading about  [Authorize(Roles="Admin")] and i have to admit that is a solution, but that means i have to write in every method of the all controllers, and i want to have that centralized in the front-controller with IF/ELSE.

PD: If you don't know how to do this, at least try to tell me where can i find the front controller in MVC c# visual studio please.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 1):

There is no front controller in MVC. You need to create a base controller , And your every controller will inherit Base controller.

```
public class BaseController : Controller
    {

        protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            var getControllerName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName;
            var getActionName = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName;
            //Write your code here
        }
    }
```

Now Inherit your controller with Base controller.

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
    {

        //Your action goes here.
    }
```

Comment: I've tryed this but it didnt work as i wanted, i mean, i want a controller where every action pass through the FRONT Controller.

In Example: url -> localhost/FRONTCONTROLLER/controller/method/parameters

instead of localhost/controller/method/parameters

Comment: If you look at the actual name of the method its an override that catches any action executing. This gives you a hook into this point in the process allowing you to add as many actions as you'd like prior to execution. 

Unfortunately not all patterns will work in every setup. I'm as disappointed as any there isn't a ready-made way to do this like in Java/Spring but you can achieve the same functionality if you're willing to be flexible.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a front controller in ASP MVC. I think the thing you're looking for is some sort of base controller where all of the other controllers inherit from.

You can add this Authorize attribute to methods or classes (whole controllers). If every action needs this attribute I suggest to create a master controller and let every controller inherit from this controller.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using action filters.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: Yes, i considerit, and i will use this i guess, because the idea of a front controller as in php i did seems difficult. If i cant find the way to do, i'll use filters :)